# Discord.NET C# Change Content of SocketMessage

Tags: c#, reflection, message, serversocket, discord.net

So I am listening to the event whenever anyone on the server sends a message to any text channel with my bot. I want to detect swear words like "fuck" and change it to "f*ck". 
I was unable to replace my message just normally only with reflection but it did not help since it only replaced it in the instance of the SocketMessage but it did not change the message on the server.

Any solution for that?

Framework: 4.6
Discord.NET: 1.0.2

Code:

```
private async Task MsgRec(SocketMessage e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.Content.Contains("fuck"))
        {
            foreach(PropertyInfo info in typeof(SocketMessage).GetProperties())
            {
                if (info.Name == "Content")
                {
                    info.SetValue(e,e.Content.Replace("fuck", "f*ck"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await e.Author.SendMessageAsync(ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

Update I also tried this without any success:

```
var rMessage = (RestUserMessage) await e.Channel.GetMessageAsync(e.Id);
await rMessage.ModifyAsync(msg => msg.Content = e.Content.Replace("fuck", "f*ck"));
```

Comment: Could it be because you're deleting the message and then modifying it afterwards? Make sure your bot has appropriate access too.

Comment: I am not deleting it I removed that line already. Still not working.

Comment: I don't think anyone besides the Context User can edit their own message.

Answer (score 2):

Discord, like other chat programs, does not allow you to change messages of users. You can not censor what a user wrote, you can only delete the whole message.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you could try something like this

```
private async Task MsgRec(SocketMessage e)
{
    var msg = e as SocketUserMessage;
    if (msg == null) return;
    if (msg.Content.Contains("fuck"))
    {
        var newMsg = msg.Content.Replace("fuck", "f*ck");
        await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(newMsg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good idea but here the sender of the message will be the bot right? I want the user to be the sender. The only line that is now working now is:

await rMessage.ModifyAsync(msg => msg.Content = e.Content.Replace("fuck", "f*ck"));

Comment: No user can modify the content of another user's message, except the user who originally sent the message. You can delete their messages (given the permission) but cannot edit.

Comment: You could delete the user's message and the bot could write it with the replaced message" like `JanMer wrote: f*ck`